# In regards to XAML How do I check that the node is 'TextBox' element?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following XAML node

```
 <TextBox x:Name="myTextContent"
            MinWidth="278"
            Panel.ZIndex="99"
            TabIndex="3"
            IsEnabled="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="47,106,47,247"  
            AutomationProperties.LabeledBy="{Binding ElementName=lblForTextContent}"
            AutomationProperties.AutomationId="myForm_myTextContent"/>
```

I have a unit test in another class that checks to verify that the XAML node contains certain attributes (such as TabIndex) that we require in the XAML, but that attribute check should only be for certain element types, such as TextBox. In the unit test I want to ignore label elements.

How do I check that the node is 'TextBox' element?

I believe it may be something like `node.NodeType == "TextBox"` or maybe `node.NodeType.Equals("TexBox")`

Here is some of my code I know this works, but I just need to make sure I EXCLUDE any node elements that are NOT 'Textbox', thus I need to know how to check the node.NodeType:

```
XmlAttribute attrTabIndex = node.Attributes["TabIndex"];
                        if (attrTabIndex == null)
                        {

                            if (node.InnerXml.Contains("TabIndex"))
                            {
                                result = true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                result = false;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            result = true;
                        }
```

Comment: Node.Name == "TextBox"?

Comment: The way you do this stuff is a) read the documentation, b) use the debugger in Visual Studio to examine the XML elements. Is `NodeType` ever the element name? Is it even a string? No, and no. Are there any *other* properties which are ever the element name? Is there a property which is *always* the element name? Why, yes. There is.

Comment: @Evk Please post as answer, so I can mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is just xml node name:

```
node.Name == "TextBox"
```

Answer (score 0):

I know testing against a XAML is different, however, as a quick test I just created an XML document with a root element and your TextBox node, and then used the code snippet below.

There's definitely more to code here, but maybe this will push you into the right direction with what you are trying to do.

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument() { PreserveWhitespace = true };
xdoc.Load("test.xml");

bool result = true;

foreach (var node in xdoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>().Where(n => n.Name == "TextBox"))
{
    result = node.HasAttribute("TabIndex");
}
```